# Subportfolio optimisation and asset clustering with maximum cluster cardinality constraint

Tags: portfolio-optimization, cluster

Assume that $N \in \mathbb{N}$ assets are given, but the portfolio optimisation algorithm can only compute portfolios with $m<N$ assets. To compute a portfolio, I would like to cluster the $N$ assets into groups containing at most $m$ assets, and apply the portfolio optimisation algorithm to each group separately.

I could only find simple sectorial or geographical clustering as well as constrained k-means algorithm as clustering methods. How could assets be clustered into groups with a maximum cardinality constrained?

Is there some other approach to compute a portfolio for the $N$ assets with the portfolio optimisation algorithm which can only deal with $m$ assets at a time?